# What does the percentage given in the header of the "Disk" column under Processes in Task Manager indicate?

Tags: windows, process, resources, windows-8.1, taskmanager

I'm confused about what exactly is communicated by the Disk Usage column in Task Manager in the Processes tab. I get that the rows indicate how much a process is consuming. But what does the column header tell, exactly? I have assumed that it is the percentage of resources that are currently in use, but this doesn't make sense given that the sums of the disk usages vary, while the header still reads "100%".

I'm using Windows 8.1 on a Lenovo G510.

Picture shows print screens of the column at different points in time.

[image]

Comment: The controller of your HDD is 100% busy handling all IO requests. I would say it is time to upgrade to a SSD.

Comment: But how can it be 100% busy with a load of 20MB/s, while also being 100% busy with a load of 10MB/s? I don't understand this.

Comment: this has nothing to do with the speed. if it is busy handling the data this can also happen with low speeds. your 5400rpm drive is slow as hell. Replace it with a SSD like the crucial MX100 and everything is fine.

Comment: @magicandre1981 okay thank you, that resolves the issue. Put it in an answer if you like and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller of your HDD is 100% busy handling all IO requests. This has nothing to do with the speed. If it is busy handling the data this can also happen with low speeds. Your 5400rpm drive is slow as hell. Replace it with a SSD and your issues are gone.